# MySQL Indexing, single or multi-column?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I currently have a table set up like this where the 'Info' table hooks up to the 'Event' and 'Stage' tables.

EVENT TABLE

```
id | categoryId | name
1  | 1          | Event1
2  | 2          | Event2
3  | 1          | Event3
[ ... About 100 rows ... ]
```

STAGE TABLE

```
id | categoryId |name
1  | 1          | Stage1
2  | 1          | Stage2
3  | 2          | Another Stage
[ ... About 200 rows ... ]
```

INFO TABLE

```
id | eventId | stageId | info
1  | 1       | 1       | Hello
2  | 1       | 2       | Something
3  | 1       | 1       | Else
4  | 2       | 3       | More
[ ... X00,000 rows ... ]
```

- **All** my queries to the info table will include a WHERE clause for the both the eventId and stageId, there will never be a case where I'll need multiple eventIds and stageIds in a single query.
- I can not query only by stageId as they can be connected to multiple eventIds.
- As in my example above, eventIds and stageIds may not be grouped together.

MySQL queries are nothing complex, no joins:

```
SELECT * FROM info WHERE eventId = 1 AND stageId = 1
```

This being the case, I've been unsure as to whether on the 'Info' table I should index both the `eventId` and `stageId` columns separately or together as a multi-index. The information out there often ends up saying 'it depends on your setup'.

Is it faster for reads on a multi-index? Are there overheads that may not make it worth it? Should I stick with a normal index on both instead?

Comment: Multi column index on the info table, but you should really show some specific queries, because an index usually isn't a one-size-fits-all thing, like a Big Mac.

Comment: Hey Tim, I've modified the question to include a query, there are no joins or anything, all queries for data from the Info table are contained within the single table.

Comment: Please note that this Question and the Answers (so far) assume both parts of the `WHERE` use `=`.  Changing to, say, `>` invalidates the answers.

Answer (score 1):

In your specific case it may be better to use `eventId` and `stageId` in a single index, assuming that both fields would have many different values.

According to the [MySql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-indexes.html), if you have with 2 separate indexes MySql will use only one of them:

> If there is a choice between multiple indexes, MySQL normally uses the
>   index that finds the smallest number of rows.

But if one field has, for example, a few dozens values while the other has millions, it may be better to index only the other to reduce the key size.

Answer (score 0):

If your query is using both the columns ( eventId and StageId) then your index should include both these columns. Having two separate index on eventId and StageId is not going to help with queries where you need to query on both. Also looking into you data I would assume the cardinality of eventId would be small so, I will have eventId as the first in my index.

Also, if you have any query on info table  which depends only on eventId or stageId, then you can order you index and have that column first in the index. As in an index with ( eventId, stageId) will take care of queries with look up for {eventId } and also { eventId, StageId }

Also, if eventId and StageId will be unique for in info table you can simply declare it as a primary key and do away with id.